# Is there a way to inject services or return types into route resolvers?

Tags: angular

Currently every page has it's own resolver and they all call the one of two methods from their respective services, for example, findById or findPageable.

```js
constructor(private service: AnyService, private router: Router) {}

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    const id = route.params.id;
    return this.service.findById(id);
  }
```

I was wondering if there was a way to inject both the service that I want, and the return type?

I've tried using Generics for the return type but didn't have much luck, and I'm not having any luck using injections for the service type that I want too.

If I could get this right then dozens of resolvers recreating the exact same method would then become like, 2 or 3 resolvers at best.

Is this possible? thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: You can use a factory to build a custom resolver. I don't think generics will really help here. It sounds like you want to parameterize the use of resolvers?

Comment: @Reactgular It's kind of parameterizing it, yes. What I wanted was to tell the resolver "this is the service you're going to use, this is the type of object you're going to return", so in a way you're right. Factories might solve the service part of the problem, and return type isn't that big of a deal to lose on anyways since I can use any

Comment: Return types for resolvers are purely semantics. The `router.data` observable has no types anyway. So you'll have to cast when reading the value.